# why only char* is a <Bad Ptr>, and not other data types?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers

I am learning about pointers in C++. When initializing pointers, for example,

```
double* pvalue1 = nullptr;//okay
char* pvalue2 = nullptr;  //only this says, "0x00000000 <Bad Ptr>" (in the watch window of Visual C++ 2010)
int* pvalue3 = nullptr;   //okay
```

Why does only the `char` type pointer give Bad Ptr while other pointer types don't?
[image]

I don't care about the pointed-to values at the moment. I am not dereferencing them (that's why there are those errors above). I am just looking at the watch window for those three pointers.

Comment: Says where? Prints compiler warning or it is an runtime error? In case of runtime error, show how you use these values.

Comment: Trying to dereference a null pointer, no matter the type, is undefined behavior. Just don't do it.

Comment: You should really clarify *where* and *how* you're getting this "Bad Ptr." Is it in the "watch" window of VS's debugger? Is it a runtime error when streaming to `std::cout <<`? Something else?

Comment: @Angew sorry, if I wasn't clear. I meant on the "watch" window of VS. I'm just initializing the pointer and looking at the watch window, not trying to dereference or cout it

Comment: @myaut says on the watch window of pvalue2.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For most pointer types, the Watch window in Visual Studio displays the value of the pointer (the address to which it points), and allows you to access the pointed-to value by expanding the <kbd>+</kbd> icon. So for a null pointer to, let's say, `int`, it will simply show `null` or `0x00000000` or something like that.

`char*`s are handled differently. Here, the Watch does not show the pointer value at all, but directly interprets the pointed-to data as a `NUL`-terminated string and prints that. This of course means that a null `char*` does not give meaningful results, hence the `Bad Ptr`.

In other words, Watch itself automatically does the dereferencing for `char*` pointers (and only for those).

Comment: Thank you. Ach, I had confused myself with "pointer value" and "pointed-to value". So the "Value" column in Watch window is the "address to which it points"(="pointer value"), in the case of pointers.

Comment: @CamiloBravoValdés The string terminator is the [ASCII character `NUL`](http://www.asciitable.com/), not a C++ null pointer constant.

Answer (score 12):

Presumably, whatever you're using to display the pointer values will also display whatever string a `char*` pointer points to, since such pointers are sometimes used to point to strings.

In this case, being null, it doesn't point to any string, so whatever is displaying it tells you that instead.

Comment: The other two pointers also don't point to any double or integer value at the moment, but they are not bad pointers. Why is that?

Comment: @HJS: Whatever displays the pointers presumably doesn't try to display whatever `double*` and `int*` pointers point to; only the strings that `char*` pointers often point to, since that's what you'd want to see if you were using the `char*` for that purpose.